# Which Linux should be used to build Android

Tags: android, linux, android-build

I have to compile the latest build of Android. Google Docs provide enough information but do not direct you about what should you use.

I do not have much experience with Linux, and do not know which one should I use. Which one is the most suitable for what I need?

After then, what are the packages that are required as prerequisites to compile the latest build of Android?

Comment: http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html#setting-up-a-linux-build-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For JellyBean:**

OS: Ubuntu  (Could do on any other as well, but detailed steps exist for ubuntu/other debian distros)

**Tools:**

> openjdk-6-jdk python git-core android-sdk

**Build Tools:**

> git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev
>   libc6-dev ib32ncurses5-dev ia32-libs x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev
>   lib32readline5-dev lib32z-dev libgl1-mesa-dev g++-multilib mingw32
>   tofrodos python-markdown libxml2-utils

Steps outlining build jellybean is in [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1762641) and official Google documentation [here](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html).